# Is it possible to get the last number generated from ROW_NUMBER in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I currently have such a query inside my stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO YTDTRNI (TRCDE, PROD, WH, DESCR, UCOST, TCOST, DRAC, CRAC, REM, QTY, UM, ORDNO, TRDATE, SYSDATE, PERIOD, USERID)
    SELECT 
        'AJ', PROD, WH, DESCR, 0, -TCOST, STKGL, COSGL,
        'MASS ADJUSTMENT', 0, UM, 
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS nvarchar(255)), 
        GETDATE(), GETDATE(), @inputPeriod, @inputUserId
    FROM 
        INV
    WHERE 
        H = 0
```

I am making use of `row_number()` to get a number that is incrementing itself while executing the query.

For example the query above INSERT 2018 records in YTDTRNI table. So the last number generated by this `row_number()` function is 2018.  My question now is whether is it possible to get hold of this last number generated by `row_number()`.

In another table, I have a value stored as I1000 for example. So after performing the above operation. I need to update this table with the new value of I3018 (1000+2018).

I am stuck on how to move on. Open to any advice if whatever I am doing is incorrect or not following conventions/standards.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not using an auto increment column instead of `ROW_NUMBER` ?

Comment: You could just use `@@ROWCOUNT` since the max row number would just be the number of inserted rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do a `@@rowcount` after your query

```
DECLARE @rc INT

INSERT INTO YTDTRNI ( ... )

SELECT @rc = @@rowcount
```

after that you can use this @rc to update the other table

Comment: . . `@@rowcount` can be affected by other things in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is not reliable if there are triggers in the database.  I would strongly discourage you from using it.

Instead, use `OUTPUT`:

```
declare @t table (rn int);

insert into . . .
    output (inserted.ordno) into @t
    select . . .;
```

Then you can simply do:

```
select max(ordno) from @t;
```

This captures exactly what is input into the table.